# What is the best way of querying data with JSON object (through MongoDB) from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I have generated a Mean stack app with the angular fullstack generator. In the generated parts of the project, querying data from angular controllers is achieved through a REST api. A typical get endpoint looks like this:

```
GET     /api/things
```

And this api can be used directly from controller like this:

```
$http.get('/api/things', { params : {'name': 'xxx'}})
```

With this approach, i can query data just with string parameters. **When i want to query data using a JSON object like this one {'age': {"$gte": 18}}, it does not work** since get only support strings as parameters. Now i am not sure what is the best way of querying data with JSON objects. I now have these options in my mind, but i am not sure which may work, or which way i should choose:

1- `$http.get('/api/things', { params : encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify{'age': {"$gte": 18}})})`

using this encoding i can pass the JSON object as string. But on the server side i am not sure how i can handle this string. req.query or JSON.parse(req.query) did not work.. This cannot be the right thing to do anyway, since it looks like a hack.

2- Creating another GET api like this:

```
/api/things/older
```

calling this api:

```
$http.get('/api/things/older', { params : {'age': '18'}})
```

and at the server side implementing the  Things.find({'age': {"$gte": req.query.age}})

This is of course not a REST api then.. I don't know if it works at all

3- I have seen some projects where some factories/services are implemented (i have not used one yet). They are injected to controllers, and can be used like this:

```
var things = Things.query();
```

However i also don't know whether what i want can be achieved with this approach or this is the right way to do, since as i heard we should only be using our REST api(?).

**So the question: What is the best way of querying data with JSON object (through MongoDB) from AngularJS?**

**Edit:** For the 1. option: when i pack my encoded object in another key like this:

```
$http.get('/api/things', { params : {myQuery : encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({'date': {"$gte": new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)}}))}})
```

and unpack on server like this:

```
Thing.find(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(req.query.myQuery)))
```

it works. But it somehow still does not sound right to me.

Comment: Add another key for params object so strings are in that query param. ...`{ params : {myQuery: encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({'age': {"$gte": ..}})}`  ...then access with `req.query,myQuery`.

Comment: I will edit the question